# Still cannot load windows 10 even after using boot-repair

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

So i was trying to make my windows 10-pc a dual boot with ubuntu 15.10.After the installation,the windows-10 loader cannot be found in the boot menu.And so i used boot-repair.Doing it created two options in the boot menu.I tried clicking both,but windows still cannot be loaded.Please help:(

BTW,this is my link "http://paste.ubuntu.com/14993962/"

Comment: How did you manage to install grub legacy to MBR for BIOS boot? But anyway UEFI and BIOS are not compatible. Windows is installed in UEFI mode, so you really want Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode. Boot-Repairs advanced mode can convert a BIOS install to UEFI, by totally uninstalling grub and reinstalling the UEFI version of grub. It looks like Boot-Repair may have done that? But you have to boot with secure boot off for grub to be able to boot Windows. Ashu's answer below looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

In your pastebin, it's mentioned that:
**Please disable SecureBoot in the BIOS. Then try again.Do you want to continue?**
So you should disable secure boot in your BIOS completely.
Also make sure that Windows 10 and Ubuntu are both installed in EFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Boot Repair, you could try my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) I recommend you start with the USB flash drive or CD-R version, although this will require disabling Secure Boot, at least temporarily. If you can boot to both Windows and Ubuntu with rEFInd, you can boot to Ubuntu and install the PPA or Debian package. If this works, you can try re-enabling Secure Boot, although this may require jumping through some extra hoops, as described on the [rEFInd Secure Boot page.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html)